# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android

Here is my java code. I want to show login to another page. JSOn SJon

```
public void jsonen()
{
 String result = response.toString();

 try{

 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

}
    catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }



    Log.i("RESULT", result+"");
```

Comment: In which line you are getting error? Show the line.

Comment: 11-29 13:16:02.860: E/log_tag(648): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: I am asking in which line of your java code? If you dont know, please provide full logcat.

Comment: There are too long to show logcat in this box. What should I do.

Comment: Show only the re color errors over here.

Comment: 11-29 13:16:02.860: E/log_tag(648): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    11-29 13:16:02.860: I/RESULT(648): {"teamStatus":"1","userName":"\u7530\u4e2d","userID":"000000001","teamID":"000001","teamName":"FC Tokyo","admin":"1","backNo":"1"}
    11-29 13:16:02.860: I/RESULT(648): +++ LOG: entry corrupt or truncated

Comment: Show me the line no 88, And 191 in you login.java

Answer (score 2):

as in log you are getting `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray` in webservice response.so try to convert string to JSONObject instead of JSONArray as:

```
    JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(result);
     //get value from json object
    teamStatus = jsonobj.getString("teamStatus");
```

Comment: 11-29 12:46:34.219: E/log_tag(986): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @user3044615 : please update your latest code and logs in question to get more help

Answer (score 0):

For parsing and getting data form a JSON Us this:

Add a JsonParser.java in your src. And java file will be like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    } 
}
```

And Now add UserFunction.Java file in src. And it will be like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;

public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    private static String loginURL = YOUR_URL;

public UserFunctions() {
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }
}
```

And your login.java will be:

```
String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
// check for login response
try {
//do your staff
}catch{
}
```

Comment: Just let me know if it doesn't help you.

Comment: CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet and CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost are String return type. I can't change JSONObject. some red line will appear...

Comment: What is 88 and 191 line in login.java file?

Comment: String str = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/football365/responseJson.php",pp);    // Line 88    if(edit_txt_Password.getText().toString().equals("")||edit_txt_Password.getText().toString().trim().equals(null))
     {
      showAlertDialog(Login.this, "Password", "Enter Password", false);
      edit_txt_Password.requestFocus();
    }    // line 190,191,192,193

Comment: May I know you can or not?

Comment: Problem is in your json parsing . Check my updated answer and let me knowe if you have any problem?

Comment: For details plz check this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: Sorry,Friend. I have to go outside with some problem. I'll be back and check your codes soon... Thanks, for your kind.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and fix it. Check your php files, especially print("") before conversion on JSON.